# Troubles with IMAP - UID does not comply with the IMAP standard

Tags: c#, outlook, imap, mail-server

I have created an IMAP-Server (I use the component from LumiSoft). It is working so far. But when I now connect with Microsoft Outlook 2010 to it, I will receive the fallowing message many times:

```
    Your server reported a UID that does not comply with the IMAP 
    standard. This typically indicates a server bug. Your program may 
    not function properly after this.

    MsgSeqNum 2, New UID 14536. Prev UID: 14558, Next UID: 0.
                Protokoll:        IMAP
                Server:           192.168.1.61
                Anschluss:        143
                Fehlercode:       0x800CCCDC
```

I think I am doing something wrong when the Client is requesting the MessageInfos.
Does someone can give me an idea, what I can do to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that outlook complains about "Next UID: 0."

How many messages you have in folder(zero ?) ?

Comment: Hi Ivar - I have found it out. The Problem was, that I haven't give the UID's in sorted List. When I sort it, it is working.